# How can I implement transfert learning with tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on a deep neural network, and I want to make a transfer learning to my model, I have founded a ckpt who where generated from another model, and I want to use this ckpt in my own model, the problem is that my model is completely different "numbre of layer, number of output", my question is how can I use the ckpt in my lowest layer ?

I use Tensorflow

Thanks

Comment: do you have the architecture of the other ckpt?

Comment: yes, I have the architecture

Comment: how do you want to use it as your lowest layer?  A couple options come to mind, your model could take as input (only the other model) or (the original data and the other model).  If you take in the original data and if it is a different shape as the output of the other model you'll have to do something like how **wide-and-deep** are put together.  Let me know and I can suggest something specific.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [tf.train.Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) class. There is `var_list` parameter which you could use to set up a correspondence between saved weights and variables in the current graph.